# Loop and dynamic slide content changing in angular using jquery swiper

Tags: angular, angular5, swiper.js

I have to change the contents after sliding in angular.I changed my object value after sliding.But it doesn't rerendered in html.Can anyone pls help me to achieve it.Below is my jquery swiper event

```
   var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      direction: 'horizontal',
      loop: true,
      speed: 700,
      replaceState: true,
      initialSlide: 1,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      loopedSlides: 2,


      onSlideChangeStart: MoveToNextOrPrevious,
      mousewheelControl: false
    });


  function MoveToNextOrPrevious() {
  if (mySwiper != undefined) {      
 if (mySwiper.swipeDirection == "next") 
   {   self.Navigate('swiperight');
   }
   }
  }
```

In Navigate function I changed my object value.But it doesn't changed in html

Thanks,

Comment: We can help if you show us what you've done and what you've tried. At the moment it can be any of numerous reasons your code doesn't run as expected. Expand your question and we might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks,I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may very well be related to zones. Angular is run in a zone when doing change detection, and 3rd party libraries are not automatically run inside the angular zone.

In your constructor you can inject NgZone and then call `zone.run` with a callback

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

private MoveToNextOrPrevious() {
  this.zone.run(() => { /* your previous code */ });
}
```

This should schedule your code to be run inside the angular zone and therefore your changes should be picked up by the change detection.

It's explained in more detail [in the docs for NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone).

Comment: @kamalav How does it not work? I think you need to be more specific. Can you include more details with what errors you see, if you have anything in your console logs and anything else that might be of interest?

Comment: no.there is no error.whether i need to navigate to route again to change the content,after using this ngZone

Comment: currently iam having 3 slides with 3 objects.After sliding one slide.Iam changing contents of all slide in typescript.After using zone js also its not reflecting

Comment: Can you inject a ChangeDetectorRef and call `markForCheck()` or `detectChanges()` after you change the content, maybe with a `setTimeout`?

Comment: content updated but after some times.can i stop slide for completion of one operation

Comment: @kamalav What do you mean "within the swiper"? Does the swiper update properties of your data contexts, i.e. properties of the objects you display in your view?

Comment: no.not like that.It slides before my content change.I have to slide manually after changing my contents.can i do that

Comment: pls help me to achieve this

Comment: Well yeah, if you do something like `onSlideChangeStart: () => { this.updateContent(); this.MoveToNextOrPrevious(); }`. I'm not sure if I understand your question though..?

Comment: no,Iam having 3 slides.If i swipe slide 1 ,it is navigating to slide2 .before completion of  my operation  this.MoveToNextOrPrevious();(this is my custom method.here Iam getting api resonse)